# Show multi-line text editor for a string property of my user control in property grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

How can I show a text editor for a string property of my user control in property grid, like below:

[image]

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What `string property` do you want to create? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should register [`MultilineStringEditor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.multilinestringeditor(v=vs.110).aspx) as [`UITypeEditor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor(v=vs.110).aspx) for your string property, using an [`Editor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute, this way:

```
[Editor(typeof(MultilineStringEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public string MyProperty {get;set;}
```

To do so:

- The `Target Framework` of your project should be a complete framework, like `.Net Framework 4.0`
- Add `System.Design` reference to your project.
- Add using:

  ```
  using System.ComponentModel.Design;
  using System.Drawing.Design;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean I think it is recommended for you to explain more. But if you want to show text in your form, select Label from the toolbox menu.